# How to make text black in preferences.xml, so that I don't have white text on a white background?

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences

I created a basic implementation of a settings menu, using this [android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html). As you can see from the gif at the bottom, is that the text is showing up white, and I have a white background. Is there a way to set the theme to light or something, so that the text is readable?

Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="test_key"
        android:title="@string/button.preference.unit"
        android:persistent="true">
        <ListPreference
            android:key="test_list_key"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/testListArray"
            android:entryValues="@array/testListValues" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        initToolbar();

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_settings.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can force a theme on app start like so, which is documented on the Android developer site under [Apply a theme to an Activity or application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)

As stated in the documentation, you can either force a pre-set theme at the  activity level on your activity xml page:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
```

or the application level in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
```

If it makes more sense, you could always just cherry-pick the properties you want to override in a custom theme:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text_light</item>
</style>
```

....and referencing as appropriate. Application level provided as example:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Full reference for names & values of all available styles and themes can be found at the end of the linked document

Comment: Thanks. I had to extends @style/theme.appcompat.light to get it to work. :)